# Finding the Z distribution given area

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Gauges are used to reject all components for which a certain dimension is not within the specification 1.50 ± d. It is known that this measurement is normally distributed with mean 1.50 and standard deviation 0.2. Determine the value d such that the specifications “cover” 95% of the measurements.

I tried to use the invNorm function on my calculator and look at the z-score table, and I keep getting 1.64. However, the solution to this problem says that the z score ranges:

P(−1.96 < Z < 1.96) = 0.95

I am confused as to how the textbook is getting 1.96. Could anyone clarify?

Comment: 95% of the distribution lies between the 2.5% point and the 97.5% point. So if you want a 95% (two-tailed) interval you look up the 97.5% value for the upper limit of it.